# Load bulk pdfs to DB2

Tags: pdf, db2, load, blob

I am a newbie to DB2 and is currently facing a some difficulties in loading pdf files into the database. I have a location where there are around 10000 pdf files and i want to load it into a table which has got a VARCHAR column (filename) and the BLOB column (the file). I did some googling and could see that the LOAD utility by IBM can do this using the "lobs from" parameter. Is there any better way of doing this considering performance. My table is going to grow really big as we have requirements to keep these files for a long period. Any better approach/hints which I can try out would be a help

Comment: Are you re-inventing a wheel ?  Many companies use content-management solutions for similar requirements (instead of home growing a solution). Consider that approach first.     Regardless, you should define "really big" in numbers (edit your post). Consider range partitioning the table based on date. Consider each range having dedidicated tablespaces.  If DB2 is running on Unix/Windows consider using LONG tablespaces to hold the BLOB object. BLOB columns involve direct-reads (slow) instead of using bufferpools which negatively impacts performance.

Comment: "Really big" will be like 15K * 365 * 7. The data has to be persisted for 7 years and every day we get around 15K files. Each file will be 100KB

Comment: You should edit your original question to give new facts, such as those numbers, because people want to see facts in the question not in the comments. It increases the chances of getting better answers.   Meanwhile your numbers are comfortably smaller than 1Terabyte, which many would consider a small database. But so much depends on the workload for that table, how often and in what way the documents are accessed, altered, versioned, searched in bulk etc.  None of that information is in your original question, but can influence the responses.